# How to get availability status of middleware services which is running on ibm cloud?

Tags: apache-kafka, ibm-cloud, ibm-mq, apiconnect

IBM internally monitor services which is offered on cloud but somehow I need to get status of middleware services such as kafka,API Connect etc. It will help me to automate things if some service stopped/not accessable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To monitor your provisioned instances of these services you could exercise them.  For example on API Connect create an API called /health and curl the API to verify it is working.  For kafka create a topic to check the health.